# Nhibernate Criterion - select rows in table A of TypeId defined in Table B

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, criteria

the title is confusing sorry, if you can think of a better one, please change it.

I have three tables, say, bikes, owners and a relationship table (something like many to many) that defines all owners of a bike, or all bikes of an owner.

[image]

So, I want to select All bikes of OwnerId 1
But, my mapping is like so:

```
BikeOwners references one Bike
BikeOwners References one OWner
```

How do I write the criterion in nhibernate to do this?

Right now, I am trying:

```
            DetachedCriteria crit = DetachedCriteria.For<Bikes>()
            .Add(Expression.Eq("OwnerId", _ownerId));
```

and it errors out saying there isn't any `OwnerId` in Bikes table, which I understand..

Hope the question is clear.. If you need any details, please ask!

---

<sup>I know I can get first get a list of all Bike id's from `Bike owner` table and then use that int array to get all bikes in `bikes` table - BUT - it is two database access and I am doing it manually, there should be a way to do this in one go, right?</sup>

This is my plan b, if all else fails, I'll do this.

Thanks

Comment: How are your entities defined / mapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your entities. I have mocked up a sample entity, just adopt it to yours.

```
public class Bike
{
    public int BikeId;
    public IList<BikeOwners> BikeOwners;
    public string BikeName;
}

public class Owners
{
    public int OwnerId;
    public IList<BikeOwners> OwnersBikes;
    public string OwnerName;
}

public class BikeOwners
{
    public int Id;
    public Owners owner;
    public Bikes bike;
}
```

Now, you are going to write your nhibernate criteria like this:

```
DetachedCriteria crit = DetachedCriteria.For<Bikes>()
    .CreateCriteria("BikeOwners") //from Bikes class
    .CreateCriteria("owner")   // from BikeOwners class
    .Add(Expression.Eq("OwnerId", _OwnerId)); //from Owners class
```

obviously, you need to modify it to your entities and names.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's more column in the BikeOwners table, it shouldn't be represented in the domain model at all. Bike and Owner should be mapped as a many-to-many relationship. Also, I find it unusual that a Bike can have multiple Owners.

Comment: I agree with the proposed solution. I think he presented this domain as an example, just ignore that part.